# How to make the onboard virtual keyboard displayed on greeter page (lockscreen)

Tags: greeter, touchscreen

Have recently installed Elementary (Loki version) on my Chuwi H13 computer. Have activated the onboard virtual keyboard to "show when needed" and most of the time when I'm logged in and would like to type things in Google search fields and in terminals and such, it works just fine! BUT when locking the screen (wether manually or automatically due to inactivity), and I want to login again, I cannot type any password because I have no physical keyboard attached and the Onboard virtual keyboard is not visible on the lockscreen! Very annoying! Any suggestions would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Its sad elementary OS have basic things like these disabled in the newer version. Worse the community itself does not care to address these elementary aspects of the OS. But post a question on Mac OS UI....

Comment: That means you made the touchscreen work right? What did you install to make it work? I installed it on a Hi10 Plus a while back but couldnt make the touchscreen work.

Comment: Yeah got it working. But did no special at all. It just worked out of the box. It probably has to do with different HW I assume.